# Strange "reindexing error" converting Series to DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Series objects, which from my perspective look exactly the same, except they contain different data. I have attempted to convert them to DataFrames and to put them both in the same DataFrame as separate columns. For some reason I cannot fathom, one of the Series will be converted happily to a DataFrame and the other one refuses to be converted when placed in a container (list or dict). I get a reindexing error, but there are no duplicates in the index of either Series.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd


s1 = pickle.load(open('s1.p', 'rb'))
s2 = pickle.load(open('s2.p', 'rb'))
print(s1.head(10))
print(s2.head(10))

pd.DataFrame(s1)  # <--- works fine
pd.DataFrame(s2)  # <--- works fine
pd.DataFrame([s1])  # <--- works fine
# pd.DataFrame([s2])  # <--- doesn't work
# pd.DataFrame([s1, s2])  # <--- doesn't work
pd.DataFrame({s1.name: s1})  # <--- works fine
pd.DataFrame({s2.name: s2})  # <--- works fine
pd.DataFrame({s1.name: s1, s2.name: s1})  # <--- works fine
# pd.DataFrame({s1.name: s1, s2.name: s2})  # <--- doesn't work
```

Here is the output, although you can't see it here, there is overlap between the index values; they are just in a different order. I want the indexes to be matched when I combine them into the same DataFrame.

```
id
801120    42.01
801138    50.18
801139    50.01
802101    53.77
802110    56.52
802112    47.37
802113    46.52
802114    46.58
802115    42.59
802117    40.85
Name: age, dtype: float64
id
A32067    0.39083
A32195    0.28506
A01685    0.36432
A11124    0.55649
A32020    0.41524
A32021    0.43788
A32098    0.49206
A00699    0.37515
A32158    0.58793
A14139    0.47413
Name: lh_vtx_000001, dtype: float64
```

Traceback when the final line is uncommented:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sm2286/Documents/Vertex/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame({s1.name: s1, s2.name: s2})  # <--- doesn't work
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 224, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 360, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5236, in _arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5534, in _homogenize
    v = v.reindex(index, copy=False)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2287, in reindex
    return super(Series, self).reindex(index=index, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2229, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2247, in _reindex_axes
    copy=copy, allow_dups=False)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2341, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3586, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2293, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Traceback when line 13 is uncommented:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sm2286/Documents/Vertex/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame([s2])  # <--- doesn't work
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 263, in __init__
    arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5359, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5453, in _list_of_series_to_arrays
    indexer = indexer_cache[id(index)] = index.get_indexer(columns)
  File "/Users/sm2286/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2082, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: Can you include the output from the print head commands?

Comment: Also the full traceback, please.

Comment: Sorry, meant to do that before posting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation the difference between the Series was that the latter contained missing values. Removing them fixed the issue.